# How do I translate 1-26 to a-z in BASH?

Tags: bash

This is a part of a comp sci homework question.

I want to translate [1-26] to [A-Z] using a bash script.

```
#/bin/bash
if [ $1 = -u ] && [ $2 = -s ];then
    #statements
    echo $3 | tr '[1-26]' '[A-Z]'
fi
```

don't worry too much about about the if statement, thats part of the question I am working on.

When I run ./file.sh -u -s 2
The output is

```
B
```

But when I run ./file -u -s 16
The output is

```
A6
```

I want it to output

```
P
```

Comment: What will be the output of `./file.sh -u -s 216`?

Comment: well it was unexpected but it gives me BAC

Comment: What is the expected output of it?

Comment: undefined? 216 is greater than 26 so nothing I guess

Comment: `tr` is meant to transliterate one character with another.

Comment: ok so its not possible to do 10 to J? As 10 has two characters and J has one?

Comment: Not easily (if at all) with `tr`.

Comment: `216 = 2 1 6 = BAF` or `216 = 21 6  = FX` or `216 = 2 16 = BP`

Comment: `tr '[1-26]'` is the same as `tr '[126]'` : It covers only chars 1 2 and 6, and they are mapped to A B and C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array of characters and just specify an index:

```
chars=("", {A..Z})
i=26
echo ${chars[i]}  # Z
```